# Filter TreeMap of dates by maximum value of each month

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, treemap

I have a collection like below currently stored as a `TreeMap` for sorting. Note that each month has multiple entries. How can I use Java 8 streams to filter this by the max value in each month?

```
date=value
2010-01-01=2100.00, 
2010-01-02=2108.74, 
2010-02-01=2208.74, 
2010-02-02=2217.92, 
2010-03-01=2317.92, 
2010-03-02=2327.57, 
2010-04-01=2427.57, 
2010-04-02=2437.67, 
2010-05-01=2537.67, 
2010-05-02=2548.22, 
2010-06-01=2648.22, 
2010-06-02=2659.24, 
2010-07-01=2759.24, 
2010-07-02=2770.72, 
2010-08-01=2870.72, 
2010-08-02=2882.66, 
2010-09-01=2982.66, 
2010-09-02=2995.07, 
2010-10-01=3095.07, 
2010-10-02=3107.94, 
2010-11-01=3207.94, 
2010-11-02=3221.29
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is the following:

- create a Stream over all the entries in the Map
- collect that Stream into a new Map where the key corresponds to the year-month part of the Map and the value is the current entry. In case of duplicates, only the maximum element with regard to the date will be kept
- create a new Stream again on the values of that intermediate Map
- and finally collect it into a `TreeMap`.

Assuming the initial Map is of type `TreeMap<LocalDate, Double>`, this would be an implementation (this code uses static imports from the `Collectors` class):

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, Double> filtered =
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect(groupingBy(
                e -> YearMonth.from(e.getKey()), 
                collectingAndThen(maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()), Optional::get))
           )
           .values()
           .stream()
           .collect(toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(); },
                TreeMap::new)
        );
```

In this code, the map is first grouped by the year-month using [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). The classifier returns a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object from the `LocalDate`. The `downstream` collector is used to collect all the values having the same year-month into a single value: in this case, we therefore use [`Collectors.maxBy(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) to select the maximum value according to the comparator comparing each entry `LocalDate` key ([`comparingByKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--)). Since this collector returns an `Optional` (in case the Stream is empty), we wrap it into a [`Collectors.collectingAndThen(downstream, finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) where the finisher just returns the optional value. At the end of this step, we therefore have a `Map<YearMonth, Map.Entry<LocalDate, Double>>`.

Finally, we keep the [`values`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) of this intermediate map to collect each entry into a new Map, where we explicitly create a `TreeMap`. Since we know there are no duplicates here, the merging function simply throws a `IllegalStateException`.

Sample input / output :

```
2010-01-01=2100.00
2010-01-02=2108.74
2010-02-01=2208.74
2010-02-02=2217.92
2010-03-01=2317.92
2010-03-02=2327.57
2010-04-01=2427.57
```

->

```
2010-01-02=2108.74
2010-02-02=2217.92
2010-03-02=2327.57
2010-04-01=2427.57
```

Comment: Looks like there's a lot of api to internalize in the collectors and classifier area. I'd better start reading up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `LocalDate` for this:

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();
// ...
```

#### Here's a functional solution

```
Map<Month, Optional<Double>> max =
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
       e -> e.getKey().getMonth(),
       TreeMap::new,
       Collectors.mapping(
           e -> e.getValue(),
           Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())
       )));

System.out.println(max);
```

Which prints

```
{JANUARY=Optional[2108.74], FEBRUARY=Optional[2217.92], MARCH=Optional[2327.57], ...}
```

#### Here's an imperative solution (just in case)

```
Map<Month, Double> max = new TreeMap<>();
for (Entry<LocalDate, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Month month = entry.getKey().getMonth();
    Double value = max.get(month);

    if (value == null || value < entry.getValue())
        max.put(month, entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println(max);
```

Which prints

```
{JANUARY=2108.74, FEBRUARY=2217.92, MARCH=2327.57, ...}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a `Map<LocalDate, Double>` as return type, i.e. keep only the maximum date, day included.

Comment: Yea, I want TreeMap<LocalDate, Double> back... Seems like that's an easy change from the above. Thanks for this, I'll use it to get more familiar with collectors.

Comment: @Patrick Actually, it is a not so easy change ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33706746/1743880))